# How to avoid the encoding of parameter added to URL in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular JS application I'm dynamically adding a parameter to the URL of the page. Say my page URL is `www.hello.com/products` , using `$location.path` I'm just appending a value to URL, and now my URL will be

```
www.hello.com/products/Nokia%20Phone
```

The value which I appended was "**Nokia Phone**", but the value is getting displayed in encoded form. How can I make sure the correct value gets displayed in the browser URL, or any way to decode it and then display?

Comment: The actual URL *has* to contain the `%20`. You *cannot* force the browser to display it in decoded form, that's entirely up to the browser to decide.

Comment: A browser cannot read whitespaces, the `%20` is the default encoding to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

The URL is supposed to be always encoded. In order to avoid the %20, you should either remove the spaces or replace them with a '-'.

According to [RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt),

> "...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL."